# Extract IPs after specific delimiter

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to extract only the IPs from a file, organize them numerically and put the result in another file.

The data looks like this:

```
The Spammer (and all his/her info): 
Username: user 
User ID Number: 0 
User Registration IP Address: 77.123.134.132 
User IP Address for Selected Post: 177.43.168.35 
User Email: email@address.com
```

Here is my code, which does not sort the IPs correctly (i.e. it lists 177.43.168.35 before 77.123.134.132):

```
import re

spammers = open('spammers.txt', "r")
ips = []
for text in spammers.readlines():
    text = text.rstrip()
    print text
    regex = re.findall(r'(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})$',text)
    if regex is not None and regex not in ips:
        ips.append(regex)

for ip in ips:
    OrganizedIPs = open("Organized IPs.txt", "a")
    addy = "".join(ip)
    if addy is not '':
        print "IP: %s" % (addy)
        OrganizedIPs.write(addy)
        OrganizedIPs.write("\n")
        spammers.close()
        OrganizedIPs.close()

organize = open("Organized IPs.txt", "r")
ips = organize.readlines();
ips = list(set(ips))
print ips
for i in range(len(ips)):
    ips[i] = ips[i].replace('\n', '')
print ips
ips.sort()
finish = open('organized IPs.txt', 'w')
finish.write('\n'.join(ips))
finish.close()
clean = open('spammers.txt', 'w')
clean.close()
```

I had tried using [this IP sorter code](http://www.secnetix.de/~olli/Python/tricks.hawk#sortips) but it needs a string were as the regex returns a list.

Comment: Maybe theres a smart way but why not just split on "." and map int to the list you get and sort the list of int-lists?

Comment: @deinonychusaur that's exactly what I'd do!

Comment: Don't use real IP address in your example.

Comment: @deinonychusaur actually I lied, my answer SHOULD work, but sorting them lexicographically should work if you fill empty spaces with "0"s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

LOG    = "spammers.txt"
IPV4   = re.compile(r"(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})")
RESULT = "organized_ips.txt"

def get_ips(fname):
    with open(fname) as inf:
        return IPV4.findall(inf.read())

def numeric_ip(ip):
    return [int(i) for i in ip.split(".")]

def write_to(fname, iterable, fmt):
    with open(fname, "w") as outf:
        for i in iterable:
            outf.write(fmt.format(i))

def main():
    ips = get_ips(LOG)
    ips = list(set(ips))      # uniquify
    ips.sort(key=numeric_ip)
    write_to(RESULT, ips, "IP: {}\n")

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 3):

Or this (saving you string formatting cost):

```
def ipsort (ip):
    return tuple (int (t) for t in ip.split ('.') )

ips = ['1.2.3.4', '100.2.3.4', '62.1.2.3', '62.1.22.4']
print (sorted (ips, key = ipsort) )
```

Comment: Very pretty! I tend to default to the "obvious but slow" answers :)

Comment: Personally, I'd have gone with `lambda`: `sorted_list = sorted(ips, key=lambda ip: tuple(int(t) for t in ip.split('.')))`, but your answer is just fine (and does *exactly* the same thing =P).

Comment: or `lambda ip: tuple(map(int,ip.split('.')))`, but we're really just re-hashing what Hyperboreus did quite readably!

Comment: @adsmith Agreed, except `lambda` with `map` as you described is a bit faster.

Comment: My apologies for the newbie-ness but do I just add that into my existing code? If so, where?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sorted_ips = sorted(ips, key=lambda x: '.'.join(["{:>03}".format(octet) for octet in x.split(".")])
```